# Email charset. HTML emails. PHP mail()

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send email using mail() PHP function.
Text is cyrillic, and when I receive the message I've something like this:
Н�! �цио� �альный

Other words are correct.

Here's the my headers:

```
$header = '';
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: \"Example.com\" <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->_data['subject']) . '?=';//works fine, but when I'm trying to use it for content, I'm receiving encoded text
@mail($this->_data['to'], $subject, $this->_html, $header);
```

Comment: I guess that `$this->_html` content is not encoded properly.

Comment: I've tried to print $this->_html to browser, and it was perfect. Should I encode this?

Comment: Have you tried `@mail($this->_data['to'], $subject, utf8_encode($this->_html), $header);` ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Content-Encoding:base64 ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Didn't help :(